# How do I recover data from route angular rc4

Tags: typescript, angular

in app routes:

```html
{ path: 'calculator', component: CalculatorComponent, data: {physical: Physical}},
```

in settings comoponent:

```html
if(this.selectedPhysical) {
   this.router.navigate(['/calculator', this.selectedPhysical ]);
}
```

The result of the navigation is trying to do this (which is obvisouly wrong):

```html
http://localhost:3000/calculator;pK_Physical=4;fK_Measurement=2;dateString=5/22/2016;weight=270;height=70;hips=27;waist=51;neck=18.5
```

So how do I pass the data to the route?

in calculator component, I have the following.  How do I retrieve the route data passed in?

```html
ngOnInit() {
    this.route
       .data
       .subscribe(v => this.selectedPhysical = <Physical>v);
            
   console.log("phys = " + this.selectedPhysical);
}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It would be great if you would not use the snippet feature for code that is not runnable. Most of your question consists of entirely useless brightly colored buttons. Use the `{}` button instead.

Comment: Just use a shared service to communicate between components. Data is currently only for data added statically to routes, everything else the router provides is reflected in the URL

Comment: Great .. I just started using this site, because its the only place to get angular2 help..  I will attempt to use the {} buttons, do you want me to redo the post? or will you tell me what I'm doing wrong in the routing?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code that depends on updated data into the `subscribe(...)` callback

```
ngOnInit() {

   ** problem is here **, I've tried every combination of things and nothing works.  Its always undefine.

   this.route
       .data
       .subscribe(v => {
            this.selectedPhysical = <Physical>v;
            console.log("phys = " + this.selectedPhysical);
       });

   // don't know about these          
   this.selectedSex = this.userSettings.sex;

   //console.log('route id =' + this.route.snapshot.params.id)
}
```

Comment: I've done what you suggested and it is still undefined when I use it.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks.,.

Comment: What is undefined?

Comment: this.selectedPhysical.

Comment: This means that the passed data is `null`. Hard to see from a few code snippets what's going on. Can you provide a Plunker?

Comment: Okay in some more testing, I discovered the above edits.  Any ideas now? Thanks again.